# Ensuring imports are valid in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

During the build or linting phase of a Typescript based project, is there any way to ensure that all imports are:

- valid (paths don't point to inexistent files)
- used (no unused imports)

Asking, since we recently ran into an issue whereby our project appears to have built and passed linting, but failed to run on our dev server due to an invalid relative import path, following CI/CD.

For example, the passed the build step, but failed at runtime, since the actual path should have been `../utils/date`:

```
import { parseDate } from '../../utils/date';
```

Also, the following was greyed out as not used in Visual Studio Code, but not caught as part of linting or building:

```
import { displayInfo } from '../../utils/display';
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the relative path errors in your project, I suggest you use the typescript alias way.
My typescript configuration:

> jsconfig.path.json

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "asssets/*": ["public/assets/*"],
            "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
            "hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
            "helpers/*": ["src/helpers/*"],
            "screens/*": ["src/screens/*"],
            "services/*": ["src/services/*"],
            "state/*": ["src/state/*"],
            "theme/*": ["src/theme/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "coverage"]
}
```

And finally you should extend this file to the tsconfig.json config file.

> tsconfig.json

```js
{
   ...
   "extends": "./jsconfig.path.json",
   ...
}
```

it will pass all relative paths in the project you have used.

Comment: Good to know, but if a developer in the team introduces something that could cause a runtime breakage,  I would like to catch it at build time. I am not sure this solves the issue, but simply provides an alternative resolution method?

Comment: Can you provide me some of your codes and used paths? maybe it can be better to help you to fix the problem as soon as possible.